# ¿Como asignarle estilos css a las etiquetas "<a>" creados con "echo"? PHP

Tags: php, css

Tengo un echo que página los datos de la tabla

```
<?php
for ($page = 1;$page <= $number_of_pages;$page++) {
    echo '<a href="index2.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a> ';
}
?>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es asignarles los estilos a los enlaces

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Deberías ponerle una clase ```<a class='miclase'>hola</a>``` y en tu __css__ crear un estilo con ese nombre y listo

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Ya lo tengo. He hecho la llamada desde el css y funcionando.